# adding lists into a set java

Tags: java, list, set

How do I add a list of things into a set?

When I do set.addAll I get an error

required type :Collection <? extends List>

provided type :List

```
public static Set<List<Food>> getAllMealPlans(Set<Food> foods, int numMeals) {
        Set<List<Food>> set = new HashSet<>();
        List<Food> aList = new ArrayList<Food>(foods);
        List<Food> sortedList = aList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.meal)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        set.addAll(sortedList);
```

Comment: The types here are a little confusing.. are you after Set<List<Food>> or Set<Food>.  If the former, then you want set.add(list), if the later then set.addAll(list) (and correct the type of the set).

Answer (score 4):

```
Set<List<Food>> set = new HashSet<>();
```

This `set` object is a `Set` of `List` s. This means every item in the `set` is a `List<Food>`.

> How do I add a list of things into a set?

As you want to create a Set which contains multiple lists, you can simply use `set.add()`. This will insert the `sortedList` as an item in the set which will end up what you are looking for.

```
set.add(sortedList);
```

### When to use addAll()?

> Adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection.
> Elements to be added may be specified individually or as an array.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)

### Possible enhancements

1. As you are already using java stream, I will get rid of `aList` variable like below.

   ```
       List<Food> sortedList = foods.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.meal)).collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
2. You can actually remove stream operations. First collect set items to a List object and then perform sorting with a method references in your comparator.

   List foodList = new ArrayList(set);

   foodList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Food::meal));